# How to make a interactive legend with chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

In the examples of ChartJS there's an interactive legend wich allows you to hide/show a result set in the graph, i.e. http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart

I've been looking through the documentation but the only references to the documentation I found are about creating an attached legend to the graph, not this kind.

Is there an option to show this kind of legend that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the Chart.js Github project, [Release Version 2.0.0](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v2.0.0) :

> #### Major new features
>
> • Charts that combine visual types such as bars and lines
>    • Chart titles
>    • **Built-in legends that are interactive by default**
>    • *... and so on ...*

You must be in version 1.X.X or something, so you cannot have it.